# Using javascript array.reduce to remove duplicates

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am having a bit of challenge learning it myself from web tutorials. Please help me to solve the problem below.

**Problem:**

Write a function that takes two or more arrays and returns a new array of unique values in the order of the original provided arrays.

In other words, all values present from all arrays should be included in their original order, but with no duplicates in the final array.

The unique numbers should be sorted by their original order, but the final array should not be sorted in numerical order.

**Use only Array.reduce to solve this ! This is what your solution should look like:**

```
function unite(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
  return arr1;
}

unite([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

I am not able to understand how I can use reduce here. All the internet examples are so easy compared to this. https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/boiling-down-arrays-with-array-reduce.html

**My wrong solution:**

```
function arrayDiff(resultArray, element){
    var idx = anotherArray.indexOf(element);
    if(idx != -1){
        resultArray.push(element);
        return resultArray;
    }
}

function unite(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    var arr = [];
    var r1 = arr1.reduce(arrayDiff);
    var r2 = arr2.reduce(arrayDiff);
    var r3 = arr3.reduce(arrayDiff);
    arr.concat(r1).concat(r2).concat(r3);
    return arr;
}


r = unite([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
console.log(r);
```

Error: ReferenceError: anotherArray is not defined

Comment: well, that's because `anotherArray` is not defined. What that variable is supposed to refer at?

Comment: Yes, `anotherArray` is not defined. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Bergi - I just saw the example here - `var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(
  function(total, num){ return total + num }, 0);`. Looks like total is the result variable. So, I followed that example and made anotherArray as my result variable. This is confusing.

Comment: If you look again on the example you provided you will notice that `total` is the first argument.

Comment: @Bergi yep, already realized that and decided to remove it at all

Answer (score 7):

To handle multiple array parameters, you can use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Thanks to that, your function can take **N** parameters, it is more generic.

Then, you can flat all your array parameters, and start to **reduce** your data. When you will reduce our array, you will create a new array by excluding redundant data. So you will start with an **empty** array, and you will populate it through the reduce process.

```
  function unite(){
    //Flat array arguments, then process to reduce data
    return [].concat.apply([], arguments).reduce(function(result, current){
      //If my result array doesn't get current element
      return result.indexOf(current) === -1
      //concat current element to result and return it
      ? result.concat(current)
      //Otherwise, just return actual result array
      : result;
    }, []);
  }

  var array = unite([1,2], [1,6,2,3], [4,5]);

  console.log(array);
  //[1,2,6,3,4,5]
```

**EDIT 06/02/2017:**

Now, you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in order to handle multiple parameters, by destructuring the assignment for example.
Moreover, we can improve performance by using the `indexOf()` operation with the bitwise operator `~`.

```
function unite(...data) {
  return [].concat.apply([], data).reduce((result, current) => {
    return ~result.indexOf(current)
    ? result
    : result.concat(current)
  }, []);
}

console.log(unite([1,2,3], [1, 4, 4, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: I pretty much wrote the exact same solution, but I'll just up-vote yours :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to check whether the `element` is already in the `resultArray`, not in some `anotherArray`. With that, it could kinda work:

```
function arrayDiff(resultArray, element){
    var idx = resultArray.indexOf(element);
    if (idx == -1) { // add only when not already found in the result array
        resultArray.push(element);
    }
    return resultArray; // always return the resultArray even if we didn't add to it
}

function unite(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    var r0 = [];
    var r1 = arr1.reduce(arrayDiff, r0); // supply some start accumulator argument
    var r2 = arr2.reduce(arrayDiff, r1); // and pass the results through so that
    var r3 = arr3.reduce(arrayDiff, r2); // duplicates are filtered amongst all arrays
    return r3;
}
```

Comment: Did not understand this - supply some start accumulator argument

Comment: @stack1: You know what the [second parameter of `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) does, don't you?

Comment: @stack1 btw, this solution does not solve your original task (but that's good, now you have chance to improve it)

Comment: @stack1: Yes, that one. We start with the empty array, then reduce over the first `arr1` to get all non-duplicate values from there, then we reduce with that result as the starting values over `arr2` to add the values that are not already in there, etc

Comment: @zerkms: Did you mean the `!=`? Not intentional :-)

Comment: @Bergi nope ;-) "Write a function that takes two or more arrays"

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, yeah, reducing over the arguments… I wonder why it shouldn't work with none or a single array though.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, a lot cleaner/shorter:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  var test = [];

  for ( var i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
    for (var j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++ ) {
      if ( test.indexOf(args[i][j]) == -1 ) {      
          test.push(args[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return test;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
function unique(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(results,currentItem){ 
    //using array include
    return results.includes(currentItem)? results: [...results,currentItem];

    //using array find
    //return results.find(function(result){return currentItem===result})?results:[...results,currentItem];
  },[]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is very powerful, but can be confusing. Make sure you always initialize the accumulator and return the accumulator from the reducer function.

```
    let originalArray = [[1,2], [1,6,2,3], [4,5]];

    let arrayFiltered = originalArray.reduce((acc, arrayvalue) => {
      arrayvalue.forEach(item => {
        if(acc.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        acc.push(item);
      }})
      return acc;
    }, []);

  console.log(arrayFiltered); //[1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5]
```

The value of each number is checked inside the forech loop, if it exists in the accumulator, if not it is pushed in.

https://jsfiddle.net/bradrice/bq84wry2/1/